# Union of \cdots and \hdots

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a symbol in math mode that look like the union of `\vdots` and `\hdots`, i.e., a cross made of five dots? Something like this:

```
 .
...
 .
```

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) offers no solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you thinking to something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\plusdots}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \sbox0{$+$}%
    \vcenter{\baselineskip=.3\wd0 \lineskiplimit=0pt
      \hbox to \wd0{\hss.\hss}
      \hbox to \wd0{.\hss.\hss.}
      \hbox to \wd0{\hss.\hss}
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\[
a+b\plusdots c
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely simetrical. In any case, what does `.\hss.\hss.` do?

Comment: @Manuel It looks like a square; `.\hss.\hss.` places the three dots in the allotted space at the same distance from each other.

Comment: @Manuel It is _enough_ symmetrical for me:) However, egreg, I will wait with accepting the answer until I am not sure enough that some more elegant solution does not exist.

Comment: @egreg May be in my mind it was not the same distance betwee horizontal dots than between vertical dots. In any case, couldn't you do `\hbox to \wd0{.\hss.\hss.}` “vertically” with the three `\hbox`es and forget about manually setting `\baselineskip`?

Comment: @Manuel Of course not